# How do I learn parameters per input example in TensorFlow without using too much memory?

Tags: memory, machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network

I want to train my TensorFlow model to learn some parameters *separately for each input element* - in particular, I want it to learn the initial states of an LSTM network for every input in my training set. The goal is to use these initial states as an embedding.

In order to loop through my input data, I use a `PaddingFIFOQueue` that goes over my input stored in `.tfrecord` files as `SequenceExample`. If I just allocate a huge tensor for the learned initial states, my memory gets exhausted. As my input data are loaded in batches, I was wondering if there is some way to split the learned initial states up in batches, too. But when and how can I save those data to disk? And how do I make sure the same initial states come up when the same batch is read again? Also, I know that Adam keeps track of changes to all trainable variables – can I somehow tell Adam to swap out its memory, too?

Comment: You can use `Saver` with custom variable list to save and load your intermediate states. You may need to write your own optimizer that uses `Saver` to load existing weights from disk on demand

Comment: I've come up with this working toy example: https://gist.github.com/elektrowolf/4ef4b03091ef623d5c90b2e8189be089 This keeps the data in main memory and only moves them to the GPU when necessary. However, data transfers are done synchronously; it would be nice to have them in a queue. In my production code, I memmapped the initial state matrix to use less main memory, too.